# How to store a struct in a linked list

Tags: c

So I'm dealing with this problem that I have to put a struct into a linked list, but I can't get it to work properly. Which means when I try to print a certain data from the struct through the list, I just get like an address or something. Here is a sample of my code. Any small tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time! PS I have no clue how to put color to my code here. If you could tell me about that as well I would be grateful <3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



typedef enum {red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black} Color;

typedef struct rect{
    int id;
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
    int area;
    Color colour;
    int filled;
}rec;

/*Linked list node */
typedef struct Node{
    rec data;
    struct Node *next;
}N;

N *head;
N *tail;

void add_list(N *p)
{
    N *new_node;
    new_node = (N*)malloc (sizeof(N));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *new_node = *p;
    new_node->next = head;
    head = new_node;

}

void show_list()
{
    N *p;
    
    p=head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", p->data.x);//lets say i want to print data.x
        p = p->next;
    }
}


void free_stack(void){
    N *p, *next_node;

    p = head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        next_node = p->next;
        free(p);
        p = next_node;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n, max_w, max_height, i, col;
    rec *obj;
    N s;
    char tmp[8];
    head = NULL;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    //simple example of stdout
    //fprintf(stdout, "HELLO");
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &n, &max_w, &max_height);
    obj = (struct rect *)malloc(n * sizeof(struct rect));//allocating memory for all the shapes
    if(obj == NULL){
        printf("ERROR!");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d %d %s %d\n", &(obj + i)->x, &(obj + i)->y, &(obj + i)->w, &(obj + i)->h, tmp, &(obj + i)->filled);
        if((((obj + i)->x) < 0 || ((obj + i)->x) > max_w) || (((obj + i)->y) < 0 || ((obj + i)->y) > max_height)){
            printf("rectangle %d has wrong definition", i);
            return -1;           
        }
        if(strcmp(tmp, "red") == 0){
            
            (obj + i)->colour = red;
        }else if(strcmp(tmp, "green") == 0){
            
            (obj + i)->colour = green;
        }else if(strcmp(tmp, "blue") == 0){
            
            (obj + i)->colour = blue;
        }else if(strcmp(tmp, "yellow") == 0){
            
            (obj + i)->colour = yellow;
        }else if(strcmp(tmp, "cyan") == 0){
            
            (obj + i)->colour = cyan;
        }else if(strcmp(tmp, "magenta") == 0){
            
            (obj + i)->colour = magenta;
        }else if(strcmp(tmp, "black") == 0){
            
            (obj + i)->colour = black;
        }
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        //printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", (obj + i)->x, (obj + i)->y, (obj + i)->w, (obj + i)->h, (obj + i)->colour, (obj + i)->filled);
        (obj + i)->id = i;//id of each rect
        (obj + i)->area = ((obj + i)->w * (obj + i)->h);//area of each rect
        add_list(&s);
        

    }
    show_list();

    
    free_stack();
}
```

Comment: Hm. You `add_list(&s)`, but `s` was never initialized. I think your `add` function should not take a node, but a `rec` as argument. The node also duplicates all data. Perhaps you shouldn't create an array of n records first. Just read input into a temporary record and create a list node.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So what you are saying is, to NOT store my data into an obj[n] struct but instead read each obj individually and automatically store it in the node?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. It seems that the data is stored in the linked list and that the array is only an auxiliary structure for input. Or do you need both data stuctures?

Comment: So basically, we are given values of a shape (lets say square) and inside the rec struct im storing all those things. Then the exercise says that we have to put all these given values as a struct into a linked list. Then this linked list has to be sorted. They want us to sort it by getting the area of w*h and and then some other stuff.

Comment: And to be more precise, they want us to sort it while inserting new data

Comment: Okay, so you really only want a linked list. [Here's one way to do that](https://ideone.com/N6GsuL) with a simplified rectangle structure. It uses a single rect as temporary space for input, then creates list nodes with the rectangles as payload.

Comment: You can the do the sorting when you add the new node. The current function just inserts at the front.

Comment: Did you just do all that? oh my god dude, u are the best!. Im going to study through it carefully! Thank you so much!